# iOS pdf search highlight result

Tags: ios, pdf, cgpdfdocument, cgpdfscanner

I have found a great post here http://web.archive.org/web/20131122162015/http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=184 that sow how to use scanner but how to highlight the result?

Answer (score 1):

Try [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten).
It has some bugs for Type 0 font but you can get the idea how to highlight text.
It does highlight text for other fonts.

Comment: do you know how to fix this bug?

Comment: Not yet. Currently working on that issue. I will post the solution when I find it.

Comment: basically there is problem in parsing of CMap in PDFKitten source.
Fix the parsing of CMap and you ll be good to use it.
It will work good for standard PDFs.

Comment: @Swaroop Is there any fork of PDFKitten that works with right to left languages (Arabic, Farsi, Hebrew)?

Comment: there is nothing special in right to left languages.. If you get correct values from CMap/Differences/Encoding you can resolve your issues.. There is not a fork of PDFKitten which corrects all of the above things.